# Allowing Rest Api to access only from browser call

Tags: angularjs, rest

we have developed rest api using web api 2 and accessing it from Angular 4 front end application using Jwt web tokens. Here how to restrict accessing web api end points from tools like fiddler, postman etc even when they are sending request with valid jwt token (which is copied from browser local storage)?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the referring URL. If there isn't one or it is not one you trust, then it didn't come from your website